# How to pass id value to controller instead from query string while getting details of page in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to pass insured id to controller while getting insured details which looks like:

// GET: /Insured/Details/123456789

But I don't want to pass this id number 123456789 in query string for security reasons.
Can somebody suggest me the best way. I am new to MVC.

Thanks

Comment: If you have access to the form, i would use `FormMethod.POST` which will post the details of the form without the queryString. but in reality if someone wanted to get\modify the ID's they could quite easily modify the html to achieve this.

Comment: I am not sure that is a secure way of doing it.

Comment: There is no way to stop a person changing a web pages HTML once its served to the client, but what you can do is add `Authorisation` functionality to see if they are allowed access to the data requested, but that is a different aspect. If what you are asking is about hiding the values from the `QueryString` then the best way is to `Post` the values back.

Comment: If i use post method, then also people can see the insured id from page body, am i correct?

Comment: That is what people are saying below. you need to validate that the person logged in has access to the id you are posting. not just rely on someone not being able to edit the id on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try submitting the value as a hidden parameter via POST. You'll need to use a form to do POST submits though. You can't use links.

```
<form method="POST" action="/Insured/Details">
    <input type="hidden" name="insuredid" value="123456789"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

You would then get the value via request parameter. If using Java servlets, it would look something like this:

```
String myInsuredId = request.getParameter("insuredid");
```

I imagine it would look similar to other platforms as well.

NOTE: Although passing values as hidden parameters hides the data from view, this does not prevent people from sniffing the submitted data or checking the HTML source of your page. If you really want to make this secure, you'll need to use some form of encryption/security. Try looking into HTTPS posts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sanitize your input in the controller, for example if the customer is logged in you could check that the ID passed to the controller truly belongs to the customer.

Anything that is passable in request (whether it's POST or GET) is spoofable.

You should also look into serving the page over HTTPS.

E.g. (asp.net MVC / C#)

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    if (Check(id) == false)
    {
        // Handle invalid input
        throw new HttpException(404, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    }

    // create the model
    ...
}
```